# How to fix corrupted Administrator account or create new admin account in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, administrator, user-profiles

I have a Windows Vista system whose profile seems to have been corrupted.
Many solutions indicate that you create another admin account, log in as that account, and delete the offending profile information for the account that is corrupted.

Here's the twist:

There are two accounts on this System - 1. Administrator Account 2. Standard Account.

It's the Administrator Account which has become corrupted. Attempts to do any user management / create a new account under the 'Standard Account' leads to UAC prompt for a user/pass. The admin account comes up by default asking for a password (of which, there is none).

When you click 'OK' - nothing happens (no doubt due to the fact that the account is corrupted, so it can't verify who or what is trying to allow the administrative privilege).

Is there a way to fix this account, or create another administrator account to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I would try logging in to Safe Mode and activating the Administrator account first.

net user administrator /active:yes

net user administrator *new_password*

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reinstalling Windows Vista from scratch because a corrupted Administrator account messes with the whole computer...not a good place to be.  If you do an in place upgrade to Win7, that could fix your issue, not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. After failing to update java from my main account I thought, "Well, maybe this is one of the programs that doesn't work under UAC" and tried to log in as the administrator account for the first time in months. Vista said that the profile could not be loaded and returned to the login screen.

My problem was fixed by restarting the computer in safe mode. The admin account was then available. Oh, it complained about a damaged profile and said it was using a default one, but it still let me log in. And then I was able to get into the users control panel, create another adminstrator user, and even delete the existing administrator's profile since there was nothing in it I needed to keep.